# image upload through json in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

1. I'm using carrier wave for image upload and trying to do upload
   image through json,but its not going to save value into database
   .While  image name is coming in controller correct here
   @Employee_events.external_doc=params[:external_doc] .But its not
   going to set in this @Employee_events.external_doc variable , as i
   thing may be issue will be multipart. But d'not know how to use in
   json.

   > .js file

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var evnt = {};
           $("#Event_dialog-form").dialog({
               autoOpen : false,
               height : 400,
               width : 600,
               modal : true,
               buttons : {
                   "Enter" : function() {

                       evnt.external_doc = $('#imgid').val();


                       $.post("/employee_management/add_event", evnt, function(data) {
                           if (data) {
                               alert("Data entered successfully");
                           } else {
                               alert("Oops! some error occured");
                           }
                       });
                       return false;
                   },
                   Cancel : function() {
                       $(this).dialog("close");
                   }
               },
               close : function() {
                   //allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
               }
           });
           $(".EventEntryDialog").click(function() {
               var Ed = $(this).attr("id");

                $('#user_id').val(Ed);

               $("#Event_dialog-form").dialog("open");
           });
           });
   ```

   > **Controller**

   ```
   def add_event

             result=TRUE
           @Employee_events=EmployeeEvent.new

            @Employee_events.external_doc= params[:external_doc]

            puts  @Employee_events.external_doc.to_s

            respond_to do |format|

              if @Employee_events.save

             format.json { render :json => result }
            else
             return FALSE 
            end
           end

          end
   ```

Comment: You can not send/upload a image via json!. You need use html!

Comment: Yup i'm also using in view file html. but actually i need when i click on link a dailogue box should open  n after browse  it goes to upload .